# Перезепись данных в поле по событию

Tags: javascript

Суть проблемы, есть поле Резерв со значением.
есть форма с полями, но при отправки формы надо что бы от Резерва отнималось число указанное в одном из полей формы, без перезагрузки страницы.

пока получилось вот так но когда добавляю туда обработчик и прочие скрипты то перестаёт работать, перезапись идёт после обновления и почему-то в начале в резерв указывается 0 а не то число что в начале должно

вот ссылка на реализованный пример. [ПРИМЕР](http://jsfiddle.net/bhw5pe09/)

Comment: Что-то я не сильно понял вопрос.. При первой загрузке будет подставляться 0, так как в localStorage нет ни какого значения, а потом при перезагрузке страницы уже будет подставляться значение, которое хранится в localStorage.

Comment: @TF03, автор ждёт значение из html при первой загрузке, а сам вставляет в этот html значение 0